# RTL8822BE Bluetooth device

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, realtek

after i got my wifi working ([RLT 8822BE wireless problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002957/rlt-8822be-wireless-problems)) I still got problems with Bluetooth. It is the same device as for wifi, the Realtek RTL8822BE. 
I installed the kernel 4.14.
Somehow its there. As the relevant part of

```
$ sudo lshw
```

shows:

```
*-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth Radio
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 2.10
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

So - i dont know what to do. I found that:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1110a2dbe69831abdcf119c3a9a4c4ef2d0905f8#diff-73c18c51833f458295d18481beb9507aR37

but have no clue what to do with it...

Can you help me?

Lui

Edit:
Could this help? i typed:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.517473] usb 1-5: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    5.023742] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.023759] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.023762] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.023765] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.023770] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.051195] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    5.051197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    5.051198] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    5.051216] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    5.051217] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    5.051217] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    5.051254] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    5.051271] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    5.051272] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    5.051272] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    5.051273] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    5.083272] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[    5.373340] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.373342] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.373345] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.135385] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   15.327417] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   15.677974] usb 1-5: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   15.679651] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
[   15.679653] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
[   15.685329] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
[   15.686830] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   15.686837] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 14, total size 20270
[   21.586992] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.586999] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.587008] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   38.862067] usb 1-5: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   39.028085] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
[   39.028087] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
[   39.028144] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
[   39.029844] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   39.029852] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 14, total size 20270
```

Specially the line:

[    5.083272] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked

looks suspicious, no ?

Any ideas?

When I try:

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm
>
```

..and nothing for more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Check, whether the kernel you are using contains the patch. If not, a newer kernel is needed. If the kernel contains the code, install firmware for your bluetooth device and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfrtunately I dont know how to check if the kernel contains the patch. And which patch should I search?

Comment: I have the same problem using kernel 4.18.7-arch1-1-ARCH in ArchLinux. The firmware files from @Jeremy31's answer are already present. Machine is a ThinkPad A485

Comment: you have a syntax error: `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`, dont forget 2nd '  !

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem might be that you install doesn't have the firmware for bluetooth, in terminal do

```
cd /lib/firmware/rtl_bt
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
```

Then shutdown and boot

Comment: Hm - very strange - it worked for about 5 minutes and now I am back to no bluetooth working. What can that be ?!

Comment: Add results for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm` to your question now that you have the firmware

Comment: Hey - i rust realised. Now it works! So - i activated it, right ? Thank you Jeremy!

Comment: Hm - its not working again. Sometimes (really not often) it works. Mostly it doesnt. Is there still hope ?

Comment: Hey there, long time since my last entry. So - my bluetooth still doesn't work (only from times to times). May the last entry here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777199/bluetooth-le-and-ubuntu-16-04-sometimes-works-other-times-not?rq=1  be a possibility for me?